# Como mudar um checkbox do padrão para imagem

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um e-commerce para uma loja de roupas e eles querem utilizar opções de cores e tamanhos igual ao do netshoes. Abaixo segue a imagem. Sei que é uma opção feita em cima de um checkbox.

[image: Cor_Tamanho_Netshoes]

Minha dúvida seria, como mudar um checkbox do padrão para imagem.

Comment: Já pensou que não precisa ser _checkbox_ alterado, que teria que envolver um monte de plugin em _jQuery_ ? Faça um monte de _div_, preencha com a imagem e cria uma função bem simples no _javascript_ que toda vez que esse elemento com cor for clicado, que o _javascript_ preencha um _input_ com o valor da cor, o que iria equivaler ao seu _checkbox_.

Comment: Tenho uma ideia, tem skype pra gente conversar? Também quero desenvolver uma loja em CI

Comment: Na verdade, isso é uma Lista não ordenada `<ul><li>`, modificadas por jQuery e CSS, com eventos. Funciona como se fosse checkbox (mais para radio buttons).